# Is Cartography a craft or a profession?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, pathfinder-1e

Simple question, for pathfinder is Cartography used as a skill classified as "craft " or "profession"?

For reference:

[Craft Skill](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/craft.html#_craft)

[Profession Skill](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/profession.html#_profession)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is **no official response**, but it can actually **be both a Craft and a Profession** according to your interpretation.

Pathfinder SRD mentions neither one.
*Song and Silence* (a [dnd-3.0](/questions/tagged/dnd-3.0) product) contains the Royal Explorer prestige class whose prerequisites also list 8 ranks in Profession (cartographer).

**It could be a Craft skill.** Cartographers produce tangible items (maps) upon commission and earn money in selling them. Also, a masterwork map is a sound concept.
Pathfinder also lists calligraphy among the [Craft](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft) skills; and it is a good relative of cartography.

**It could also be a Profession skill.** Cartography could include hiring explorers, being on the move and providing services beyond the actual map making. Someone already [included it among Profession skills](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/community-creations/richard-s-lab/alternative-rules/extra-skills/professions) in his own home rules.

---

My own feeling is biased toward Craft (cartography) or Craft (map making) rather than Profession (cartographer).
As a side note, this is an example of what the D&D Next skill system is going to seamlessly address.

Comment: +1. Also, which one you take it as would allow you to accomplish different things with it. Does the player want to e.g. make masterful maps, or have surveying abilities?

Comment: I pretty much treat craft and profession skills as interchangeable. Profession(lumberjack) seems like a weird grey area, otherwise.

Comment: Craft is what I'll go for, after looking through the cartography guilds samples, especially the old maps, it's as much art as helpful geographical info; and for things like the Mappa Mundi even more so!
This is will be supplimented with Knowledge skills and Survival, to both know about an area and do the physical mapping.

Comment: If it's both, can they give each other synergy bonuses?

Answer (score 3):

Craft: Cartography, Knowledge: Geography are the ways I would split it up.  Cartography implies making the maps (thus accurately transferring to a chosen medium), where a character who is aware of the landscape would therefore have a knowledge.  The skills would not be mutually inclusive but the DM could approve a synergy.

EDIT: I believe this covers the criteria since it is a specialized combination of painting and calligraphy which are both craft skills.

Comment: This doesn't actually address why Cartography should be a craft skill rather than a profession skill. -1.

Comment: In my initial post is "Cartography implies making the maps (thus accurately transferring to a chosen medium)".  I believe this covers the criteria since it is a specialized combination of painting and calligraphy which are both craft skills.

Comment: In that making the map is generating a physical item, it would more aptly fit a craft

Comment: I suggest you edit that into your answer, then.

Comment: Done and done.  Edited in.

Comment: ...And downvote removed. Have a nice day.